# eclipse: debug programmatically initiated process

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm programmatically executing a java process via another java process in eclipse:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, envp, dir);
```

Is there any way to tell eclipse to debug the child process?

Alternatively, I could solve this by chaining multiple launch configurations, ie launch process A, on completion launch process B - provided B could be launched in debug mode.

Comment: FYI i need to run things in different processes because i need to use jmx for other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the "Remote Debug" feature in Eclipse then you can point it at any JVM instance.  You just need to make sure that each instance is told to use a unique JDWP port.  This is how you'd do it from the command line:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y
```

So, change the 'address' part to whatever port you want, then you can point Eclipse at that port.  Here's some more information:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Comment: is it possible to 'point eclipse to that port' programmatically?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could write a plugin which would do it, or you could set up a proxy (using SSH for example), one side of which is fixed and has Eclipse pointing to it, the other end of which is defined at runtime.  It's hacky but that's how I like to do it :)

Comment: Note that Eclipse 3.5 and later can let the debugger wait for the program to connect instead of having the debugger connect to the program.  This allows you to do other things first.

Comment: Given that Java is now getting multiple releases a year I hope they consider introducing this. When I used to write C it was easy and made debugging easy

Answer (score 3):

Add a command line option to the child process as follows:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9999
```

(you can use a different port number than 9999, it's up to you, but best choose a number above 1024)

Then in Eclipse, create a Debug Configuration of type "Remote Java Application". Set the host as localhost and the port as 9999.

[This developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html) has plenty of extra information.

EDIT: Incidentally for more flexibility in specifying the command line and environment of your child process, use the `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` class instead of `Runtime.exec(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the developer works link. There was a good deal of learning from this post and answer